# Recycleview inside Nested scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

In my layout xml file, I have nested scroll view, there is recycleview inside nested scrollview.
But problem is there when I put recycleview inside nested scrollview I am not getting

- findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
- findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

and other method.

As per my requirement nested scroll is required, So what I need to do for get findFirstVisibleItemPosition or findFirstVisibleItemPosition. if I am comment nested scroll then I am successfuly get these both but nested is necessary. please help me out to overcome this issue.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true">

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rvPost"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />


        // other layout view also here...

     </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And for get position  :

```
 poistion.add(((GridLayoutManager) mCurrentLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
```

Above code work without nested scroll but not work with nested scroll.

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: @moein added code

Comment: @moein Are you check code?

Comment: Not yet, you haven't attached activity of your code

Comment: @moein i just use java code as i mention other are same as we used.